# Edge won't display Help in application Web Browser control

Tags: browser, controls, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge, Windows 10.
Our application is developed in VS2013 Visual Basic. We use a third-party Help System development tool, HelpSmith, which has worked well for us.  When users click the "?" symbol for generic help, we display help in a web browser control.  Now that EDGE is the default browser, users (and we) only get:

**This page can’t be displayed
Make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm# is correct. 
Look for the page with your search engine. 
Refresh the page in a few minutes.**

This is a huge problem for us.  Given that many users have Windows 10, and Edge is the default browser for many, how do we resolve this, since we cannot control our user's computers?

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this error, but if I want to open the HTML help in Edge, it looks bad.  The formatting is lost, the images are not shown, etc.  Any ideas?

Comment: It works fine in Chrome & Firefox.